# iPhone/iOS: Will there be called any method if a UIView is added as a subview

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, addsubview

If I add a view as a subview like so

```
[self.view addSubview:mySubview];
```

Will there be called any method on mySubview, that I could override to add some custom behavior?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Adding a view to a (new) superview triggers

`- (void)willMoveToSuperview:(UIView *)newSuperview`

and

`- (void)didMoveToSuperview`.

See the [UIView Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html) for more.

Comment: Thanks for the very quick response. I will kind of stupid, that I havent noticed the method right away myself...

Comment: Good stuff! Learned something new +1

Answer (score 3):

You can override these two:

```
- (void)willMoveToSuperview:(UIView *)newSuperview
- (void)didMoveToSuperview
```

Take a look in the documentation for `UIView` for similar methods.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, There is a method which get called if one change the **superview** . you need to override the below method in your subview class.

```
- (void)willMoveToSuperview:(UIView *)newSuperview
- (void)didMoveToSuperview
```

From [UIView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html) Doucumentation

> willMoveToSuperview:,
>   didMoveToSuperview—Implement these
>   methods as needed to track the
>   movement of the current view in your
>   view hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

exep for special purpose is far better to customize you view in init phase, you have all you need and (more important) is a synchronous call.

Comment: Does not really answer the question, does it?