# Is there a method that was called every time a UIView was show?

Tags: iphone

I'm writing a calendar app, now I have weekView, weekViewController, dayView, dayViewController, monthView, monthViewController.

what I want to do is that: when you select a date in any view, then switch to another view, I want the new view will show the same date, too.

I've managed to share the selected date among the controllers, but I don't know how to tell the view update their content every time they show?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162211/iphone-ios-will-there-be-called-any-method-if-a-uiview-is-added-as-a-subview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try placing the date updating logic in the `- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated` methods of the view controllers. [Here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewWillAppear%3a) is the reference.

Comment: Thank you, viewWillAppear is the right way, but there are still problems:  I use a UITabBarController to contains all the three controllers, and use tabBarController:didSelectViewController to get the selected date from previous controller, and set in the next coming controller. But I found that the viewWillAppear was called before the select date setting, so In fact the UIView stays the same.

Comment: I would recommend you make a global singleton object that is accessible by all view controllers which holds the date value, and read the date value from that singleton object in the `viewWillAppear:` method. This is much cleaner than your approach.

Comment: @Jerrylk if this answer helped solve your issue, please mark it as the answer (check-mark below the up/down vote arrows).