# How to automatically fit the parent view to its child views programmatically?

Tags: ios, view

I'm new to IOS development and I'm trying to make one of my parent view become automatically fit to its child views.

[image]

For example the picture above have a red circle which indicates a blank space I'm going to adjust the text upward so it fulfill the spaces and I also want that the container of all the text will automatically adjust its height to fit for its content.

Thanks.

Comment: what kinda layout is this? This is not possible with UITextView

Comment: Can you please mention which all UI components you are using ? I mean please explain your view hierarchy.

Comment: the text is all UILabel and the black screen is my UIView

Comment: You are adding UILabel programatically or in Interface builder ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the `willMoveToSuperView` and `didMoveToSuperView`

Check the answer here
[iPhone/iOS: Will there be called any method if a UIView is added as a subview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162211/iphone-ios-will-there-be-called-any-method-if-a-uiview-is-added-as-a-subview)

You can then adjust the view according to its super view. However, using auto layouts is a much preferred way.

Answer (score 0):

You Should do one thing.
First alloc your parent view and give it a frame then, when your child view will alloc and it has a frame then set your parent view's frame one's again.

So, when your child view will appear then your parent view's frame will automatically set.

Hope this helps...